# handling chunked uploads in bottle.py

Tags: python, python-requests, bottle

I'm having a little trouble handling chunked uploads from the server side using bottle.py. I'm using python requests and request-toolbelt for HTTP and upload progress tracking. I intend to use the script to upload large files hence the need for chunked uploads and avoiding reading the files in memory.
I have slightly adapted the example shown in the requests-toolbelt docs and while I can see the upload progress data , I get a file with 0 size on the server side . Here's the code that i'm using.

```
    #uploader.py
def create_callback(encoder):
    encoder_length = len(encoder)
    prog_bar = Bar(expected_size=encoder_length, filled_char='=')

    def callback(monitor):
        prog_bar.show(monitor.bytes_read)

    return callback


if __name__ == "__main__":
     m = MultipartEncoder(
        fields={'testfile': ('test.txt', open('test.txt', 'rb'), 'text/plain')}
        )

     callback = create_callback(m)

     m = MultipartEncoderMonitor(m, callback)

     r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1/upload', data=m,
                      headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type})

     print r.status_code #prints 200

#server.py

@post("/upload")
def handle_upload():
    print len(request.POST['testfile'].file.read()) #i always get zero



if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(server='cherrypy', port="8080") # I still get zero even without the cherrypy server
```

I think I have followed the instructions but I just can't figure it out where I'm missing the point.

[Edit]

I have checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040706/streaming-file-upload-using-bottle-or-flask-or-similar) which describes how to patch the files back
and relies on the Content-Range field in the headers but when I print out the request headers I can only see the content-Length

Comment: The above is working on my side I was somehow opening the file in append mode when building the MultipartEncoder . Sorry for the bother

Comment: I know you've figured out what the problem is, but I want to clarify: the MultipartEncoder does /not/ do chunked uploads. It streams the uploads. (There's a significant difference)

Comment: Thanks I kind of thought they were the same . Its back to the docs for me then :)

Comment: It's a subtle difference but it's significant as far as servers/HTTP are concerned.

Comment: So here's what I have in my head now : streaming uploads are like pipes directly to the files being uploaded to the server while chunked uploads are like uploading chunks of the file to server. so far so good ?

Comment: Yep. If you're familiar with bash, a better example is doing `cmd <file` vs `cat file | cmd`. In the first, `cmd` knows that it's reading `file` and what the length of file is. In the second, it doesn't so it will read chunks and send the chunk preceded by the chunk's length. That's the major difference.